# Better way to toggle functions

Tags: jquery, function, toggle

Right now I am toggling a div to expand and collapse

I'm looking for a more elegant approach to creating these two functions and toggling them.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
    var collapseExpand = [collapse, expand];

    function collapse (){
        $('#document').removeClass('col-sm-5').addClass('col-sm-12 col-md-2 collapsed');
        $('#stages').removeClass('col-sm-7 collapsed').addClass('col-sm-12 col-md-10');
    }

    function expand () {
        $('#document').removeClass('col-sm-12 col-md-2').addClass('col-sm-5');
        $('#stages').removeClass('col-sm-12 col-md-10').addClass('col-sm-7');
    }     

    $('.col-expand').on('click', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        collapseExpand.reverse()[1]();

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `toggleClass()` in a single function instead:

```
$('.col-expand').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#document').toggleClass('col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-sm-5 collapsed');
  $('#stages').toggleClass('col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-sm-7');
});
```

This method will remove any classes already applied to the element, and add any which are not.

Comment: Thanks, added it in

Comment: thanks! this worked like a charm. appreciate the help.